# Shell Command for Getting IP Address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface, ip-address

Is there a bash command to find the IP address for an Ubuntu box?  I need to find the IP address so I can ssh into the machine later.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`/sbin/ifconfig -a`

Comment: Yup and if you're planning on remotely administering the server, `vi /etc/network/interfaces` and set the interface to `static` (see https://help.ubuntu.com/8.10/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html)

Comment: Running this command reveals a whole list of numbers. Which one should we use? The `inet addr`?

Answer (score 27):

You can use:

```
/bin/ip addr
```

Comment: @opierce You have marked mpbloch's answer as correct, but as an FYI, you should be using this answer, as this is part of the iproute2 suite. `ifconfig` is being phased now.

Comment: You can make that shorter by just running `ip a`.

Answer (score 22):

If you have an internal address in use, checking

```
curl http://myip.dnsomatic.com
```

might be a good idea on unix shells.
Or, just plonk that URL into your browser.

---

If you get a different answer from the "`ifconfig -a`" result,
the `ifconfig` gave your internal address -- which will probably not work from outside.

---

Even if all seems fine, you could have a firewall in place that will disallow incoming **ssh** connections.
At which time you should try the port of interest from a browser on the machine at,

```
http://www.canyouseeme.org/
```

That will confirm connectivity through,

- external IP address (showing it to you on that page)
- NAT, Port Forwards
- Firewalls

Comment: True, but if that is the case, there are probably no NAT/Port Forwarding rules in place to match ssh to whatever the internal IP is.

Comment: @Kyle, Which can be added...

Comment: +1 for `curl http://myip.dnsomatic.com`

Comment: Similar to this, there is also `curl ifconfig.me`

Answer (score 21):

`/bin/hostname -i`

Comment: In this case I would suggest using ```hostname --all-ip-addresses```.               Display all network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all  network
              interfaces.  The loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this
              option does not depend on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

Comment: Shorter alternative to @lrkwz's comment `/bin/hostname -I`

Comment: Thanks @hanxue - this ought to be an answer of it's own - the shortest command with the cleanest output - just what I was looking for!  In my experience (Ubuntu), `/bin/hostname -i` just gives `127.0.1.1`, which is useless.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 13):

```
 curl icanhazip.com
```

tee hee!

*From http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2966/return-external-ip*

Answer (score 10):

```
/sbin/ifconfig|grep inet|head -1|sed 's/\:/ /'|awk '{print $3}'
```

If you need your internal adress append your interface after ifconfig, e.g.

```
 /sbin/ifconfig eth0|grep inet|head -1|sed 's/\:/ /'|awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: +1, this is exactly what *I* needed to solve a problem.  Hurray for one-liners!

Comment: +1 Without the head -1:

/sbin/ifconfig|grep inet|sed 's/\:/ /'|awk 'NR==1 {print $3}'

Comment: Thanks, it works on Debian but on OS X it doesn't work, returning some garbage. It would be great if we could come of with a line that works on both. Here is the output of ifconfig on OS X: https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/5814657

Answer (score 6):

If you are behind a NAT, and need the public IP, use this:

wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'

taken from: http://www.go2linux.org/what-is-my-public-ip-address-with-linux

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple interfaces, could be useful to specify which one you want IP. if you want IPV4 address of interface 'eth0':

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | grep "inet " | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

if you want IPV6 address of interface 'eth0':

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | grep "inet6 " | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

if you want to search for an IP between two common interfaces of a laptop, wlan0 and eth0:

```
CURRENT_IP=''
for INTERFACE in wlan0 eth0; do
    if [ -z $CURRENT_IP ]; then
        CURRENT_IP=$(ip addr show dev $INTERFACE | grep "inet " | awk '{ print $2 }')
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find out what the IP address of your router, you could run this command.

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @208.67.222.222 @208.67.220.220
```

If you are using OpenDNS for your dns server, you could shorten it to:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com
```

You could also use this command.

```
curl http://myip.dnsomatic.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Just curl this [page](http://wtfismyip.com/text):

`$ curl wtfismyip.com/text`

Comment: And how exactly is this superior to the similar services already mentioned during these years?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one line that works on Linux and OS X too, and it will return the first address that is not local:

```
ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'
```

Send credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322549/99834

Answer (score 2):

```
LOCAL_IP=`/bin/hostname -I | sed 's/ //g'`
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go about it is probably

```
ifconfig eth0
```

assuming the machine has a single IP address on the default wired interface - you might need

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

if it's on WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip address show scope link
```

It will show you the IP address of living - has link - interfaces. But it is not a bash command. Bash has no ability to know about IP and network at all.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you want to connect a remote ubuntu machine which has dynamic ip. Go dyndns.org site and open a free account. Then on the remote machine you need to install a dynamic ip tool.

```
sudo aptitude install dyndns-client
```

so you can ssh remote machine via

```
ssh username@yourdynamicnamealias.dyndns.org
```

So after configuration you will never need the remote machine ip address.

Comment: This is my preferred method for dealing with dynamic IPs.

dyndns.org is a fantastic, free service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am using:

```
LC_ALL=C /sbin/ifconfig | awk '
    /inet addr/ {
        gsub("addr:","");
        if(($2!="127.0.0.1") && ($2!="0.0.0.0") && ($2!=""))
            { print $2 };
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need just a single IP of given interface you can do:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a [public IP address of the box](//serverfault.com/a/560059/110020), you could use the following:

- `dig @ns1.google.com -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short | tr -d \"`

You could use [`dig(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/dig.1) options like `-4` or `-6` to specifically look for an IPv4 or IPv6 address; Google will provide an answer in a record of `TXT` type, which will have quotes around it when presented by `dig`; if you want to subsequently use the variable with utilities like `traceroute`, you gotta use something like [tr(1)](http://mdoc.su/-/tr.1) to remove said quotes.

Other options include `whoami.akamai.net` and `myip.opendns.com`, which answer with `A` and `AAAA` records (instead of `TXT` as in the above example from Google), so, they don't require having the quotes removed:

- `dig -4 @ns1-1.akamaitech.net -t a whoami.akamai.net +short`
- `dig -4 @resolver1.opendns.com -t any myip.opendns.com +short`
- `dig -6 @resolver1.opendns.com -t any myip.opendns.com +short`

Here's a sample script that uses all the options above to set the variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
IPANY="$(dig @ns1.google.com -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short | tr -d \")"
GOOGv4="$(dig -4 @ns1.google.com -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short | tr -d \")"
GOOGv6="$(dig -6 @ns1.google.com -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short | tr -d \")"
AKAMv4="$(dig -4 @ns1-1.akamaitech.net -t a whoami.akamai.net +short)"
CSCOv4="$(dig -4 @resolver1.opendns.com -t a myip.opendns.com +short)"
CSCOv6="$(dig -6 @resolver1.opendns.com -t aaaa myip.opendns.com +short)"
printf '$GOOG:\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "${IPANY}" "${GOOGv4}" "${GOOGv6}"
printf '$AKAM:\t%s\n$CSCO:\t%s\t%s\n' "${AKAMv4}" "${CSCOv4}" "${CSCOv6}"
```

---

If you're looking for a private IP address, or for a set of all IP addresses assigned to the box, you could use some combination of [`ifconfig`](http://mdoc.su/-/ifconfig.8) (on BSD and GNU/Linux), `ip addr` (on GNU/Linux), [`hostname`](http://mdoc.su/-/hostname.1) (options `-i` and `-I` on GNU/Linux) and [`netstat`](http://mdoc.su/-/netstat.1) to see what's going on.